# If $A$ is compact, $\lambda\ne0$ and $y$ is fixed, is there a unique $x$ with $(\lambda-A)x=y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $B$ is a compact linear operator on a Banach space $X$, we know that $\dim\mathcal N(1-B)\in\mathbb N_0$ and $\mathcal R(1-B)$ is closed.

Thus, if $\lambda\ne0$ and $$B:=\frac A\lambda$$ such that $\dim\mathcal N(1-B)=0$, then for all $y\in X$, there is at most one $x\in X$ with $(\lambda-A)x=y$. But can we guarantee that there always is such a $x$?

Answer (score 0):

A bounded operator $T$ is said to be *Fredholm* if $\text{dim}(\mathcal N(T))<\infty $,  and
$\text{codim}(\mathcal R(T))<\infty $.  In this case the *index* of $T$ is defined by
$$
  \text{ind}(T)=
  \text{dim}(\mathcal N(T))-\text{codim}(\mathcal R(T)).
  $$
It is a well known result,  sometimes called the *Fredholm alternative*,  that $I-B$ is a Fredholm
operator with
index zero  for every compact operator $B$.

Thus,  if $\mathcal N(I-B) = \{0\}$,  it follows that $\mathcal R(I-B) = X$ so, yes, the desired $x$ always exists.

Answer (score -1):

Let $ \lambda \ne 0$. If $ \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then

$$0< \dim \mathcal{N}(\lambda -A) < \infty,$$

since $A$ is compact. If $y \in \mathcal{R}(\lambda -A)$, then there is $x_0 \in X$ with $(\lambda -A)x_0=y$.

Then we have $(\lambda -A)(x+x_0)  =y$ for all  $x \in  \mathcal{N}(\lambda -A).$

Comment: Why the downvote ???

Comment: Fred, the question does not assume that $y\in\mathcal R(\lambda-A)$.  PS:  not the downvoter.

Comment: @ Ruy: the question was: if $y $ is fixed, is there a unique $x$ such that $(\lambda-A)x=y$. It is clear that no such $x$ exists if $y \notin \mathcal{R}(\lambda -A).$ so we have only to consider the case $y \in \mathcal{R}(\lambda -A)$.

Comment: The OP has already taken care of the uniqueness so the main question remaining is "But can we guarantee that there always is such a $x$?", which your answer does not address.

Comment: It is obvious that the existence of $x$, and the fact that  $y∈\mathcal R(λ-A)$ are equivalent, but it is the truthfulness of these statements,  rather than their  equivalence,  that is in question,